# Why does `:type` sometimes show `a` and other times `t`?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have these two functions:

```
cleanUp a = Data.List.filter (/=[]) a

joinByPairs [] = []
joinByPairs (x:[]) = (x:[])
joinByPairs (x:y:xs) = (x ++ y) : joinByPairs xs
```

When I load them in `ghci`, and call `:type` on them, I get these results:

```
*Main> :type joinByPairs
joinByPairs :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
*Main> :type cleanUp
cleanUp :: Eq t => [[t]] -> [[t]]
```

What is the logic of it showing `a` vs. `t`? I don't think it's because of the `Eq t` part, since I have other functions that show something like `otherFunction :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [[a]]`.

Comment: Not that it really matters, no? :P

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz No, or at least I don't think so, but it bugs me!!!

Comment: Some function in `cleanUp` (maybe `filter`) has a type signature written using the variable `a` while some function in `joinByPairs` (maybe `(++)`) has a type signature written using the variable `t`.

Comment: I don't have an exact answer, but I think it pretty much boils down to this: the GHC developers don't care very much about the names of the type variables GHC shows you. Sometimes type variables will come from what you've written, sometimes they'll come from the function(s) you're using, and sometimes the compiler will make them up from whole cloth. Sometimes this is really annoying (particularly when using `ScopedTypeVariables`).

Comment: @dfeuer Actually, the GHC devs care more than you may think. There's an awful lot of extra machinery in GHC to keep around type information provided by the user -- type synonyms and families are kept folded as long as possible, type variable names are preserved if they came from the user, and probably other subtle places you wouldn't think about off the top of your head have special cases as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of the way type variable names are chosen.  Brand-new variables get `t`.  Type variables that are named in a type signature keep the name from the type signature.  When unifying type variables, GHC prefers to keep a name that came from an explicit type signature.  If no subexpression had an explicit type signature, there's no names other than `t` to unify with.

Comment: Type variables that are named in a type signature don't always keep those names in typed hole messages, even when they are in scope with `ScopedTypeVariables`. This is obnoxious, IMO.

Comment: Ah.  I rarely used typed holes, so I haven't run into that.

Comment: Typed holes are awesome, although [not quite as awesome](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9091) yet as they [should be](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9479).